# Suzuki gsx-s1000 sometimes hard to shift gears when cold engine

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, shifting, gsx-s1000

I own a 2018 gsx-s1000 and sometimes, it's very hard to change the gears, when the engine is cold. No problem with the first gear, but starting with 2nd and up and then when I come down to neutral. After about 20-30 minutes of riding, when the engine gets warmed up, this symptom disappears and  shifting is normal. Again, this happens sometimes, when the engine is cold. Feels like the clutch is not disengaging complete. The clutch cable was checked and adjusted.To mention that I have NOT heard any strange noises from the gearbox when the issue manifests. Has anyone had this problem or any idea of what could be? Maybe the gearbox forks, or the clutch mechanism?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure it is using the proper motor oil (weight)? I'm assuming your Suzuki like most motorbikes today have a wet clutch which uses shared oil between engine and transmission. If you are using the wrong weight oil, it can affect shifting.

Comment: Hi, the oil was changed recently with 10w-40 Bel ray full synthetic at a service repair (I consulted the manual and 10w-40 was the recommendation from Suzuki). But the problem was present before the oil changing as well.